# Associate usage records with the corresponding usage plan in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Customer's resource usage:

```
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
| usage | customer_id |  timestamp            |
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 10    | 1           |  2019-01-12T01:00:00  |
| 16    | 1           |  2019-02-12T02:00:00  |
| 26    | 1           |  2019-03-12T03:00:00  |
| 24    | 1           |  2019-04-12T04:00:00  |
| 4     | 1           |  2019-05-15T01:00:00  |
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

This table shows the usage reported every hour for every customer. Minutes and seconds are always zero.

Customer's plan change log:

```
+--------+-------------+-----------------------+
| plan   | customer_id |  timestamp            |
+--------+-------------+-----------------------+
| A      | 1           |  2018-12-12T01:24:00  |
| B      | 1           |  2019-01-12T02:31:00  |
| C      | 1           |  2019-03-12T03:53:00  |
+--------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

When a customer changes his usage plan, the action is stored in a change log.

Result: associate each usage record with a usage plan.

```
+-------+-------------+--------+-----------------------+
| usage | customer_id |  plan  |  timestamp            |
+-------+-------------+--------+-----------------------+
| 10    | 1           |  A     |  2019-01-05T01:00:00  |
| 16    | 1           |  B     |  2019-02-12T02:00:00  |
| 26    | 1           |  C     |  2019-03-10T03:00:00  |
| 24    | 1           |  C     |  2019-04-12T04:00:00  |
| 4     | 1           |  C     |  2019-05-15T01:00:00  |
+-------+-------------+--------+-----------------------+
```

What I have tried: to determine the plan for a specific usage record, I take the timestamp of that record and look for the most recent plan change record in the usage plan log:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  plan,
  timestamp,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) seqnum
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
WHERE seqnum = 1 AND timestamp <= timestamp_of_the_usage_record
```

However I am not sure, how to combine that with the usage table. I tried:

```
WITH log AS (
  SELECT
      customer_id,
      plan,
      timestamp,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) seqnum
    FROM
      `project.dataset.plan_change_log`
)
SELECT
  t1.customer_id,
  log.plan,
  t1.usage,
  t1.timestamp
FROM
  `project.dataset.usage` t1
FULL JOIN log
ON log.customer_id = t1.customer_id AND log.timestamp <= t1.timestamp AND seqnum = 1
```

The result table has fewer rows than the original usage table because of the join condition. However the amount of rows should stay the same. Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, although the data in your example is a bit off for the first and third line of the end result.

```
with data as (
SELECT
  t1.customer_id,
  log.plan,
  t1.usage,
  t1.timestamp,
  log.timestamp as logt,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.customer_id, t1.timestamp  ORDER BY  log.timestamp DESC) seqnum
FROM
  resource t1
FULL JOIN log
ON log.customer_id = t1.customer_id AND log.timestamp <= t1.timestamp 
)
select * from data where seqnum = 1
```

You want to do create the sequence on the result of the join, not before.